# What are the conventional short names for variables of different C# primitive types?

Tags: c#, types, naming-conventions

*With conventional I mean i.e. what the standards or most used versions are.*

The `int i` are well known, and in many cases `string str` or the even shorter `string s`, as a generic naming of variables. What are the conventional naming schemes for the remaining C# built-in types?

- bool
- byte
- sbyte
- char
- decimal
- double
- float
- int
- uint
- long
- ulong
- object
- short
- ushort
- string

Edit:
As many people here won't answer without a background reasoning; the reason for not naming these into length, name, age etc. is because it lays in a library class to provide functionality to many projects where all the variables can be assigned to different things based on the use case.

Compare this to the `new List<int>().Add(int i);` (I know it's written as `T item`), but here I need to use multiple types in the same method, and item1, item2, item3 etc. won't make the cut.

Comment: Normally, shortened names like you have mentioned shouldn't be introduced to production code. Generic variable names cause confusion. For example, if I have `str`, `str1`, `str2`, and `str3`, who can tell me what they are representing?

Comment: @Breeze I believe it is getting downvoted because it is opinion based as there is no standard.

Comment: The OP is new, the title can be made more precises by the OP. what ever the reasons, those who down vote must provide a reason , specially for the newbies so they know what went wrong and what the issue was! maybe they can fix it or narrow down the questions scope. 
To me, The OP could ask (by editing) for C# Standard Coding conventions, that would ultimately answer his/her questions as well.

Comment: @MattRowland: Hence the phrasing "conventional"

Comment: As Bruno's answer and my comment stated, there is no convention for this because it shouldn't be done.

Comment: @Enlund: such conventions are usually language/environment /team specific. In C# you should be following its standard Naming Convention. in which you should consider using names based on a entities’s meaning rather than it’s type.   
As I said, being able to do something or not, boils down to the requirements that "you" or your project specifies and demands! 
If you want to work for a company later on, and they demand you know and follow the standard C# naming convention, then you must follow that. if your company has a specific set of guidelines, conventions, you need to follow that!

Answer (score 3):

Appart from for loops where i,j,k are admitted, I would strongly advise not to use short names. Variable are understood by the compiler whatever name you choose. However humans need a precise meaning to understand and work with your code.

Take a look at:

```
 int i;
 bool b;
```

versus:

```
int weight;
bool isAdult;
```

Doest it make any difference?

Comment: I would say it depends on the use case.
Compare
SetWeight(int weight) { ... }
vs
StoreGenericIntegerInThisObjectList(int i) { ... }

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on following a standard convention, Follow the Microsoft Naming Convention [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines), otherwise, you may stick to whatever convention you/your team is familiar/comfortable with.
As for  the abbreviation :

> DO NOT use abbreviations or contractions as part of identifier
>   names.
>
> For example, use `GetWindow` rather than `GetWin`

Basically its better to:

> consider using names based on a **parameter/field’s meaning** rather
>   than it’s **type**.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions) is the general Naming Convention which explains everything you need.